# navigator.notification.alert not working - phonegap

Tags: cordova, alert

I am doing a phonegap project for iphone, i have a phonegap alert inside a confirmation notification callback. My `confirmation (navigator.notification.confirm)` works fine but `alert(navigator.notification.alert)` not working, don't know why is it so, pasted my code below.

```
function confirmSubmit() {
    navigator.notification.confirm(
        'Are you ready to submit?', // message
        function(buttonIndex) {
            onConfirm(buttonIndex);
        },
        'Confirmation', 'Yes,No' // buttonLabels
    );
}

function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
    if (buttonIndex === 1) {
        didClickSubmitButton();
    } else if (buttonIndex === 2) {
        return false;
    }
}

function didClickSubmitButton() {
    validate();

    ----some other codes-----
}

function validate() {
    navigator.notification.alert("my alert"); // Not working
    alert("another alert") //Working
}
```

I'am testing on iphone simulator of xcode, i need your help. Thanks.

Comment: I experienced that and it does not work on iphone simulator 3.5 but it works on iPad simulator. Assuming you have called `navigator.notification.alert` after deviceready event.

Comment: device ready is there on start.

Comment: @JunM: will it work in device?

Comment: I can only confirm on android device that it works but haven't tested on iOS device. Sorry.

Comment: Does the line `navigator.notification.alert("my alert")` works if you place it at the first line of confirmSubmit method?

Comment: function validate() {
    navigator.notification.alert("my alert", null, MyTitleAlert, Ok); // Not working 
    alert("another alert") //Working
}  You call that function - alert- without all param. Check documentation an see Ved solution

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue in android.

`navigator.notification.alert()` was not working but `alert()` was working. To customize the alert I wanted `navigator.notification.alert()` to work.

So I added the plugin for notification/prompt etc as:

```
$cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

then added below code to app/config.xml:

```
<feature name="Notification">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
</feature>
```

Thus I got navigator.notification.alert() working with the title, msg, callback and button name parameters.

Comment: It should be app/res/xml/config.xml, not app/config.xml
according to http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html

Comment: org.apache.cordova.dialogs has been renamed to cordova-plugin-dialogs

Answer (score 1):

```
function validate ()
{
  navigator.notification.alert('Mesage',
                               null,
                               'Title',  
                               'OK')
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button labels should be enclosed within brackets in array like notation. See the documentation for code examples.
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.confirm

Comment: Try using == when comparing against numbers instead of ===.

Comment: it s fine since it countrole reaches just above the alert.

Comment: Or use a switch instead. Is the validate function being actually called?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if you are running it from IDE, that you have added / selected the cordova plugin for your projects in IDE itself.

For example:

If Netbeans, right click on project, select properties, select cordova from tree & click on plugin tabs, check if you have dialogs notification in selected API.

If not that is the reason, each time you will add it from command line and and if try it running from IDE it will erase/clean the plugin directory but will be fine from command prompt only if you make cordova run android.

I hope the above will help.