# Apache cordova : Alert and jquery ajax call is not working

Tags: javascript, ios, apache, cordova, mobile

I am working on small app that fetches database information in JSON format from PHP files. I am trying to write alert and jquery ajax call but both are not working/executing in app. But when I simultaneously check in browser then it is showing. I am new to Apache cordova platform. Can somebody please reply me on my issue? How can I resolve these basic issues in apps.

Platform : ios app. - running on --emulator

waiting for your response.

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    $("#defaultsetlocation").html("hello added new text");
    alert("i am alert");
    try
    {
       navigator.notification.alert('Hello', ok, 'Title', 'Button!');  
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert("doesn't support!!");
    }

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
 }
};
app.initialize();
```

Comment: We'll need to see some code of what the app is doing before we can begin to help here.

Comment: @AndrewBerry : added code above. Trying to alert first in app. In safari-> Develop option when i open then it is working all in safari browser. but not working while checking on emulator

Comment: So is your code that is retrieving the JSON from your PHP files being called? If so, where is that being called from?

I'm guessing when you hit your breakpoint on the receivedEvent it's not being hit at all?

Comment: First trying to debug things at initial stage. Then i will check for jquery ajax call and binding JSON data on UI. But in first step alert is not working in app.

Comment: The breakpoint is being hit on load but through safari browser. Not in app.

Comment: yes. It is being hit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627281/navigator-notification-alert-not-working-phonegap

This may help you out.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewBerry. But my question is why the normal alert not working properly.

Comment: What happens if you put your alert in the OnDeviceReady function?

Comment: Doesn't alert. How can i debug script in that app.

Comment: I develop using VS on windows, I suppose it depends on what IDE you use in iOS to develop the app

Comment: Not helping me this really.